# Remove certain number of div from another div using Jquery without loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all div after 12 div inside the parent div using jquery.
The markup is like :

```
<div id="dvNames" class="container grayBox float-left">
<div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_30" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_31" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_32" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_33" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_34" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_35" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_36" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_37" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_38" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_39" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_40" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_41" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_42" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_43" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_44" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_45" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_46" type="text"></div><br></div><div class="float-left margin-bottom-10 width-33-per divContainer"><div class="float-left"><input placeholder="LastName,FirstName" onchange="CheckVisitorName(this)" class="width-180 reset" name="name_47" type="text"></div><br></div>
</div>
```

I know we can get all div like inside parent div like `$('#dvNames div')`. By removing like `$('#dvNames div').remove()` removes all div. Also we can get each one by `$('#dvNames div:first')`.

So I ended up with

`for(;$('#dvNames div').length>12;) $('#dvNames div:first').remove()`

It works I intended but I feel there must be some way to **do it without loop.**

**Please help me if you know the way to do it without loop.**

Comment: Try `$('#dvNames div:gt(12)').remove()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('#dvNames > div').slice(12).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YKu5z/)

Comment: Thanks for answer, this was I looking for, Barmar's answer is also correct but in my case this suits better, since there are div inside div & using this answer help to use exact no of elements added i.e. 6. other 6 divs are used for formatting. Using this I need to do `$('#dvNames > div').slice(6).remove()` instead of 12

Answer (score 4):

Use the `:gt` pseudo-selector to select all DIVs after 11 (it counts starting with 0).

```
$('#dvNames div:gt(11)').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it works but my case suits Arun's answer better